# How to move multiple dropdown menu to right side in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I remove the margin-left, margin and padding value to 0px from the root ul tag then
all menu display in the left side and the dropdown-menu size match

---

I want to move all menus plus dropdown-menu to right. I moved the menu to the right using margin-left, margin: 15px, and padding 15px in the root ul tag and it works but the drop-menu size isn't matching, please look up the picture.

---

[output of this page] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLZnO.png

---

[expect output] [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvOLY.png

```css
ul {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 50%;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: .8;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li> <a>sport</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">football</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">soccer</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">basketbal</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a>more info</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">#</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#"> #</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `float:right` in the css, in the `ul` part. Also remove the `margin-left: 65%;` because it will make your design unresponsive since your buttons have fixed width.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: .8;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li> <a>sport</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">football</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">soccer</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">basketbal</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a>more info</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">#</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#"> #</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: How about if I give the margin:15px and padding:15px in the root of ul tags

Comment: i think i see what you mean, but i'm not sure its ideal, for responsive.. Have you tried ?

Comment: I tried many times and I didn't figure it out. why it is happening

Answer (score 0):

try like this

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
          <title> sport </title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="sport.css">
       </head>
       <body>

            <ul class="menu">
                <li > <a>sport</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li ><a  href="#">football</a> </li>
                        <li ><a  href="#">soccer</a> </li>
                        <li ><a  href="#">basketbal</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li > <a>more info</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li ><a  href="#">#</a> </li>
                    <li ><a  href="#"> #</a> </li>
                    <li ><a  href="#">#</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>

       </body>
    </html>
```

**css**

```
ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li{
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px; 
    background-color:blue;
    opacity: .8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;

}
ul li ul{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  right:-200px;
  top:0;

}
ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}
ul li a:hover{
    background-color: green;
}
ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: How about if I give the margin:15px and padding:15px in the root of ul tags

Comment: why should you give 15px for tat?

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  float:right;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: .8;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="menu">
  <li> <a>sport</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">football</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">soccer</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">basketbal</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a>more info</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">#</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#"> #</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

add in ul style

```
ul{
    float: right;
  }
```

Comment: How about if I give the margin:15px and padding:15px in the root of ul tags

Comment: This will just padding and margin to root ul

Comment: It will show output as I have in my output pictures. so, is there a way to make dropdown menu size equal

Comment: equal means what ? above style itself having equal.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Example**

Html

```
 <ul class="menu">
      <li> <a>sport</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">football</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#">soccer</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#">basketbal</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a>more info</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">#</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"> #</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
```

Css

```
  ul.menu {
        width: 200px;
    }
    ul.menu>li{
      position:relative;
    }
    ul {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      list-style: none;

    }

    ul li {
      float: right;
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: blue;
      opacity: .8;
      line-height: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      display: block;
    }

    ul li a:hover {
      background-color: green;
    }

    ul li ul {
      display: none;
    }

    ul li:hover ul  {
      display: block;
      position:absolute;
      left: 200px;
      top: 0px;
      width:200px;
    }
```

Comment: If you want free bootstrap HTML Themes, Templates, and Code Snippets. you can go on https://freebootstrapui.com website

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
    ul.menu{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        list-style: none;
        margin-left:65%;
    }
    ul.menu li{
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        height: 40px; 
        background-color:blue;
        opacity: .8;
        line-height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;

    }
    ul li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        display: block;
    }
    ul li a:hover{
        background-color: green;
    }
    ul li ul li{
        display: none;
    }
    ul li:hover ul li{
        display: block;
    }
    li {
        position: relative;
    }
    li ul {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: block;
        width: inherit;
    }
```